# Attemp to re-open an already closed object android.database.sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, loader, android-loadermanager

i have a Main activity which has a list view.
the listview items are loaded with LoaderManager.

when i click an item in the listview i open another activity that shows more information
(with "startActivityForResult")

the problem is :

when i go back(using the return key on) from the activity that shows information to the main activity and then click again i get an exception - Attempt to re-open an already closed object.

but if i go back from that activity(that shows more information) with a Button  that i made there(which is actually "finish()") to the main activity and then cllick again then i get no exception

anyone knows what is the problem?

Thanks !

```
private void display_listview()
    {
        // create an adapter from the SimpleCursorAdapter
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.row_invite_layout,
                null,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        //Ensures a loader is initialized and active.
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


        //add implementation to listview item click
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                IInvite invite = LoadFromCursor(cursor);

                cursor.close();

                mUpdateFlag = true;

                if(!mTrashFlag) // Trash Can is turned off
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InviteViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("invite",(Invite)invite);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, INVITE_REQUEST_ID);
                }
                else // Trash Can is turned on
                {
                    getContentResolver().delete(InviteContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, SQLdataHelper.KEY_ROWID+"="+invite.getID(), null);
                    ExtraDelete(invite);
                    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
                }


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        dataAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
    {
        dataAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
    {
        String[] projection = {
                SQLdataHelper.KEY_ROWID,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_CLIENT_ID,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_CREATION_DATE,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_NAME,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_NOTE,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_REQUESTED_DATE,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_TOTAL_PRICE,
                SQLdataHelper.INVITE_STATUS
        };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                InviteContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }
```

UPDATE: FIXED IT. i added this method to my main activity..

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing cursors as listview items? And why are you closing them in `onItemClick()`?

Comment: i dont store cursors. this is how loader manager works with list view

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating public static fields, but I wouldn't recomend it. You can store data in shared preferences and then retrieve it whenever you want.

Comment: i dont want to create static fields. what causing the problem? it depends on how i return to the main activity but what causing that

Comment: Problem is that you can't control GC that deletes all unused variables and objects. Best way is to store them in file, shared preferences or database depending of amount of data you want to save.